# Continuous deploys on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have everything setup and working with rolling deploys and being able to do `git aws.push` but how do I add a authorized key to EB server so my CI server can deploy as well?

Comment: What are you using to manage your continuous integration?

Comment: Shippable @JoshDavis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Shippable, I found this guide on [Continuous Delivery using Shippable and Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://blog.shippable.com/continuous-delivery-using-shippable-and-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-java-mysql-edition) that shows how to set it up on their end. Specifically, step 3 is what you are looking for.

It doesn't look like you need an authorized key, instead, you just need to give an AWS ID and AWS Secret Key that will allow Shippable to make API calls on your behalf. To do this, I recommend creating an IAM role that is specifically for Shippable. That way you can revoke it if you ever need to and only give it the permissions that it needs.